# How to configure Spring boot LDAP Authentication for particular IP and port

Tags: spring-boot, spring-ldap, spring-security-ldap

I have a problem with LDAP Authentication. I try to config LDAP configuration and using that LDAP in my spring boot login API. I don't know is it correct or not.please anybody suggests how to implement inside the login API.
Below is my LDAP configuration coding.

```
@Value("${spring.ldap.username}")
private String LDAP_USERNAME;

@Value("${spring.ldap.password}")
private String LDAP_PASSWORD;

@Value("${spring.ldap.urls}")
private String LDAP_URLS;

@Value("${spring.ldap.base}")
private String LDAP_BASE;

@Value("${spring.ldap.anonymous-read-only}")
private boolean LDAP_ReadOnly;

@Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        LdapContextSource lcs = new LdapContextSource();
        lcs.setUserDn(LDAP_USERNAME);
        lcs.setPassword(LDAP_PASSWORD);
        lcs.setUrl(LDAP_URLS);
        // lcs.setReferral("follow");
        lcs.setBase(LDAP_BASE);
        lcs.setAnonymousReadOnly(LDAP_ReadOnly);
        lcs.afterPropertiesSet();
        authenticationManagerBuilder.ldapAuthentication().contextSource(lcs).userSearchBase("ouBaseHere").groupSearchBase(LDAP_USERNAME).userSearchFilter("userNameSearchHere");
    }
```

This is my Login API code.

```
@PostMapping(value = {"/signin"})
public ResponseEntity < ?>signin(@Valid@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {
    System.out.println("Username : " + loginRequest.getUsernameOrEmail());
    System.out.println("Password : " + loginRequest.getPassword());
}
```

This is my application.propeties.

```
spring.ldap.anonymous-read-only=true
spring.ldap.base= dc=example,dc=com
spring.ldap.password=XsR453!333@#q
spring.ldap.urls=ldap://192.168.111.1:1015
spring.ldap.username=test_usr
```

Comment: simple LDAP authentication works by performing an LDAP BIND operation with a DN and a password. 'test_usr' is not a DN. You may use 'BIND_DN' instead of 'LDAP_USERNAME' to make this obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I implmented LDAP in my project, so here is the information which may help you to set up ldap in your work. You need to set up similar like the one mentioned below :

```
private LoginLdapSettings getLdapSettings() {
    LoginLdapSettings ldapSettings = new LoginLdapSettings();
    ldapSettings.setDn(/**Enter the Dn of the LDAP server**/);
    ldapSettings.setLdapUrl(/**Enter the URL of the LDAP server**/);
    ldapSettings.setLdapPassword(/**Enter the PASSWORD of the LDAP server**/);
    ldapSettings.setSearchFilter(/**Enter the SEARCH FILTER of the LDAP server**/);
    ldapSettings.setLdapUsername(/**Enter the USERNAME of the LDAP server**/);
    ldapSettings.setUserDnPattern(/**Enter the URL of the LDAP server**/);
    return ldapSettings;
}
```

Below method is when you are using Active Directory

```
private ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider getActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(){

    LoginLdapSettings ldapSettings = getLdapSettings();
    StringBuilder ldapDomain = getLdapDomain(ldapSettings.getDn());
    ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(ldapDomain.toString(), ldapSettings.getLdapUrl());
    authenticationProvider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
    authenticationProvider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(false);
    if(null != ldapSettings.getSearchFilter() && !ldapSettings.getSearchFilter().trim().isEmpty()) {
        authenticationProvider.setSearchFilter(ldapSettings.getSearchFilter().trim());
    }
    authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(ldapUserDetailsMapper);
    return authenticationProvider;
}

@Override
public void configure() throws ConfigurationException, InvalidAttributeValueException, IOException{
        auth.authenticationProvider(getActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
}
```

Below method is when you are using OpenLDAP

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    LoginLdapSettings ldapSettings = getLdapSettings();
    auth.ldapAuthentication()
    .contextSource()
    .url(ldapSettings.getLdapUrl() + "/" + ldapSettings.getDn())
    .managerDn(ldapSettings.getLdapUsername())
    .managerPassword(ldapSettings.getLdapPassword())
    .and()
    .userSearchFilter(searchFilter)     
    .userDnPatterns(ldapSettings.getUserDnPattern()) // I used this as the pattern "uid={0}"
    .userDetailsContextMapper(ldapUserDetailsMapper);
}
```

Please vote if you liked the answer! :)